# How to push existing git project (git-hub) to bit bucker?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have github project openstack in my local system,I have done some changes now I want to push it to https://bitbucket.org repository. I want to push kilo branch to my remote repository.

When try to run

```
 git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/user_name/my_project.git
```

I am getting following error.

fatal: remote origin already exists. I ran the same command which they (bit-bucket) mentioned. **I don't want to remove master, please tell me how to add my local repository to bit-bucket..**

```
[vagrant@localhost horizon]$ git branch
  master
  stable/icehouse
  stable/juno
* stable/kilo


[vagrant@localhost horizon]$ git branch -a
  master
  stable/icehouse
  stable/juno
* stable/kilo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are the steps to migrate from github to bitbucket

1.First clone the repository to your local machine using the command

```
git clone <repository url>
```

2.After cloning is successful detach your git hub repository

```
git remote -v
git remote rm origin
```

3.After detaching your github repository. Go to your bitbucket and create a repository and find the option `I have code that I want to import` and click it.

4.It would give you command which you need to run from your project directory console. The commands would be like below

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/urRepository/urproject.git #you would get your repo link from bitbucket.
git push -u origin master # to push changes for the first time
```

and it would be done.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different remote

```
git remote add bitbucket https://username@bitbucket.org/neelabh_singh/my_project.git
git push bitbucket  stable/kilo:kilo
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an existing remote named `origin`, which you can check by using,

```
git remote -v
```

Either you can delete/rename the existing remote or you can create a new remote.

```
git remote add mynewremote https://username@bitbucket.org/neelabh_singh/my_project.git
```

If you want to name it as `origin` then just rename/remove the existing origin,

```
git remote rename origin <new_name_for_old_origin>
```

**OR**

```
git remote remove origin
```